# Evaluating a limit arbitrarily close to an infinity - working check

Tags: limits, proof-verification

I'm trying to evaluate a limit:
$$\lim_{a \to \infty} a \frac{\sinh(a(x-1))}{\cosh(a)}$$
where $x$ is close to, but not identically $0$. When I plot for the domain $0\le x \le 1$ and vary $a$, it looks like the limit tends to zero everywhere except at $x=0$ where it tends to infinity. I want to prove this, but don't know how. It's easy to show that it goes to infinity when $x=0$, but I want to prove that it goes to zero everywhere else.
I'm rewriting this idea as
$$\lim_{a \to \infty,\  \epsilon>0} a \frac{\sinh(a(\epsilon-1))}{\cosh(a)}$$

I convert this to exponentials and do a lot of rearranging and manage to confirm that it goes to zero, but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is valid. Can someone tell me if it makes any sense, and point me in the right direction if need be?
My working:

$$\lim_{a \to \infty,\  \epsilon>0} a \frac{e^{a(\epsilon -1)}-e^{-a(\epsilon -1)}}{e^a+e^{-a}}$$
$$\lim_{a \to \infty,\  \epsilon>0} ae^{a\epsilon}\frac{e^{-a}-e^{-2a\epsilon}e^{a}}{e^a+e^{-a}}$$
$e^{-a}$ goes to $0$ in the numerator and denominator
$$\lim_{a \to \infty,\  \epsilon>0} -ae^{a\epsilon}\frac{e^{-2a\epsilon}e^{a}}{e^a}$$
$$\lim_{a \to \infty,\  \epsilon>0} -ae^{a\epsilon}e^{-2a\epsilon}$$
$$\lim_{a \to \infty,\  \epsilon>0} \frac{-a}{e^{a\epsilon}}$$
then using l'Hopital's rule, taking derivatives wrt $a$
$$\lim_{a \to \infty,\  \epsilon>0} \frac{-1}{\epsilon e^{a\epsilon}} \to 0$$

Comment: This is completely correct. You don't need to write $\epsilon> 0$ all the time. It is fixed anyway.

Comment: Thanks @FriedrichPhilipp I haven't done much work with limits so I was taking a guess with this method

Comment: You have to justify why you can pass to the limit inside the limit (the line "$e^{-a}$ goes to $0$..."). In general, this cannot be done.